# save promise fulfill and reject promisekit

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6, promisekit

Hi I'm trying to create a promise and then save the function fulfill and reject into in array or dictionary . I don't know if this is possible to do I get some compiler erros. I know you can store functions inside array but I think since is inside the promise I need to do something else, here is my code

```
let requestPromise = Promise<Bool> { fulfill, reject in
    self.socket.emit(message,dic)
    let dicFunc = [ "fulfill": fulfill, "reject":reject]
    self.request.updateValue(dicFunc, forKey: uuid)
}
```

I get error
Cannot invoke 'updateValue' with an argument list of type '([String : (NSError) -> Void], forKey: String)'

Answer (score 0):

The `fulfill` and `reject` variables have different types so they can't both be contained as separate values within the same dictionary or array. (Unless possibly if you make a dictionary/array that contains `Any` but that will loose needed type info.)

Check out `Promise.pendingPromise()`. You can hold an array of `PendingPromise`s.